# How to get more data and append to document, with Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm very confused on how I should ask for more data, for example, using an API, and append it to the list I already get.

Let's say we have an infinite scroll feature or a 'load more' button and when the event triggers, I load more data excluding what I already have and append it.

I tried creating an iron-router server route, but I couldn't retrieve it with Ajax, my calls were always dealing with it as it was a client route.

What is the up-to-date way of doing this with Meteor?

My attempts were

```
Router.route('/posts',{where: 'server'}).get(function(){
  // do something
});
```

And this

```
Router.route('/posts', function () {
  this.layout(null);

  var req = this.request;
  var res = this.response;

  res.end(JSON.stringify({}));
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the reactive nature of Meteor.  The core idea in pre-Apollo Meteor is to subscribe to some data such that the data returned is what you need to display at that point.

That said, for an infinite scroll, what I have seen in the past is to use a reactive var to set the "filter" of a subscription. As you scroll down, when your event triggers, you simply update the filter, which then triggers an update to the subscription (reactively), which then widens the data being subscribed to.

How you filter depends highly on your data, but basically use something that allow you to sort the data and expand the "limit count" that you return.